# migrating project to comply with google sign in requirements for iOS

Tags: ios, google-signin

I'm trying to get a google sign in button to work with my iOS app, but I'm getting this error here:
`Cannot find 'presentingViewController' in scope`

This is the code segment:

```
func handleSignInButton() {
      GIDSignIn.sharedInstance.signIn(
        with: signInConfig,
        presenting: presentingViewController // this is the line with the error,
        callback: GIDSignInCallback? = nil) { user, error in
          guard let signInUser = user else {
            // Inspect error
            return
          }
          // If sign in succeeded, display the app's main content View.
        }
    }
```

I've been told I need to migrate the way I am signing in and I found this here:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/quick-migration-guide

but I'm confused about this part here:

```
Manually connect GIDSignInButton to a method that calls signInWithConfiguration:presentingViewController:callback: using an IBAction or similar.
```

Can someone show me how to do this properly? I'm a iOS novice :)
Thanks!

Comment: This property is defined in a view controller instance. So you need to call this function from a view controller or passing it a view controller so it can display the Google sign in view from it..

Comment: @PtitXav, so I need to create a view controller class and call it from there?

Comment: The code that call your function should be in a view controller that you must pass to goggle signin. As you do not show from where you call it, it is difficult to be more precise. The point is that the signing view could be attached to a view controller which will add it in its view hierarchy or as popover.